# Trigger not executing when a Batch Update runs

Tags: vb.net, oracle, ado.net, triggers

I am using VB.Net 2008 and ADO.Net to do a Batch Update to our Oracle database. 
The updates are working, but there is a trigger on the table before the row is updated to enforce a member's termination termination date. 
*So if I was trying to set the termination date (via the batch update) to 31-Jan-2010 but the member had a claim that was processed on 2-Feb-2010 the trigger would force the termination date to be 2-Feb-2010.* However, the trigger is NOT executing when the batch update runs?

**Is there any Oracle DB Admin option that would disable Triggers on Batch Update?**

Comment: Please post the source of the trigger.  In SQL*Plus, you'd need to issue `SET LONG 40000` and then `SELECT TRIGGER_BODY FROM ALL_TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = :my_trigger`

Answer (score 2):

A direct path load through SQL*Loader can disable and reenable triggers as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_modes.htm#sthref1587)

What does the batch update do. Maybe if it does a DELETE+INSERT, rather than an UPDATE, then the trigger won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

The alter trigger command can be used to disable a trigger,

```
ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name DISABLE
```

This will show the enabled/disabled status of all triggers,

```
select trigger_name, status from user_triggers
```

Comment: The trigger is Enabled and work normally, just does execute when a batch update is ran.